Running full voltage through Transistors
Hello I am trying to create a fan controller using Arduino. The (Placeholder LED's) fans run at 12V 0.23A DC so I have an external power supply for them. I plan to control the flow of this with NPN Transistors.
But before I build it I am running it in a simulator. And I am having an issue where at times, none of the power supply's voltage is going through the transistors and other times its in parallel and the voltage across all three drops down to 4.12V.
Is there any way to run these in series to keep the same voltage? And if why the power supply's voltage is being ignored at times.



I don't think my code will be needed but in case I will have it below.
    //#include <DHT.h>
    //#include <DHT_U.h>
    //#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); 

    //#define DHTPIN A0     
    //#define DHTTYPE DHT11   
    //DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

    unsigned long time = 0;      
    unsigned long debounce = 200UL;


    float(value);
    int Temp = 0;
    int tmp = A0;
    
    int fan1State = 0;
    int fan2State = 0;
    int fan3State = 0;
    int fansOn = 0;

    int fanOne = 5;
    int fanTwo = 6;
    int fanThree = 7;
    int bF1 = 2;        
    int bF2 = 3;
    int bF3 = 4;

    int oldbFState1;
    int oldbFState2;
    int oldbFState3;

    int bFState1;
    int bFState2;
    int bFState3;

    int bCount = 0;

    int dispA = 13;
    int dispB = 12;
    int dispC = 10;
    int dispD = 9;
    int dispE = 8;
    int dispG = 11;

    void setup(){

      pinMode(dispA, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dispB, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dispC, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dispD, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dispE, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(dispG, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(tmp, INPUT);
      pinMode(fanOne, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(fanTwo, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(fanThree, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bF1, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(bF2, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(bF3, INPUT_PULLUP);

      Serial.begin(9600);

      lcd.begin(16,2);
      lcd.init();
      lcd.backlight();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Hello World.");
      delay(2000);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Boot Done.");
    }

    void loop(){


      //Temp = (analogRead(tmp)*(3300/1024));
      //lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      //lcd.print("Temperature: ");
      //lcd.print(Temp);

        // SEVEN SEGMENT DISPLAY.

      if (bCount >= 0) {

        if (bCount == 1) {
          digitalWrite(dispA, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispB, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispC, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispD, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispE, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispG, LOW);
        }
        if (bCount == 2) {
          digitalWrite(dispA, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispB, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispC, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispD, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispE, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispG, HIGH);
        }
        if (bCount == 3) {
          digitalWrite(dispA, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispB, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispC, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispD, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(dispE, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispG, HIGH);
        }
        else {
          digitalWrite(dispA, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispB, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispC, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispD, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispE, LOW);
          digitalWrite(dispG, LOW);
        }
      }
        // FAN CONTROL CODE LIES BELOW  

      int bFState1 = digitalRead(bF1);
      int bFState2 = digitalRead(bF2);
      int bFState3 = digitalRead(bF3);

      // Ehaust Fan 1

      if (bFState1 == HIGH && oldbFState1 == LOW) {

        if (fan1State == 0) {
          digitalWrite(fanOne, HIGH);
          Serial.println("B1 ON");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Ehaust Fan On.");
          fan1State = 1;
          bCount = (bCount + 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        } else {
          digitalWrite(fanOne, LOW);
          Serial.println("B1 OFF");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Ehaust Fan Off.");
          fan1State = 0;
          bCount = (bCount - 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        }
      }

      oldbFState1 = bFState1;

      // Intake Fan 2

      if (bFState2 == HIGH && oldbFState2 == LOW) {

        if (fan2State == 0) {
          digitalWrite(fanTwo, HIGH);
          Serial.println("B2 ON");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Intake Fan 1 On.");
          fan2State = 1;
          bCount = (bCount + 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        } else {
          digitalWrite(fanTwo, LOW);
          Serial.println("B2 OFF");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Intake Fan 1 Off.");
          fan2State = 0;
          bCount = (bCount - 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        }
      }

      oldbFState2 = bFState2;

      // Intake Fan 3

      if (bFState3 == HIGH && oldbFState3 == LOW) {

        if (fan3State == 0) {
          digitalWrite(fanThree, HIGH);
          Serial.println("B3 ON");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Intake Fan 2 On.");
          fan3State = 1;
          bCount = (bCount + 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        } else {
          digitalWrite(fanThree, LOW);
          Serial.println("B3 OFF");
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Intake Fan 2 Off.");
          fan3State = 0;
                  bCount = (bCount - 1);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();

        }
      }

      oldbFState3 = bFState3;
    }


Why is ground of the fan power supply connected to the 3.3V pin of the Arduino? Should that be also ground? Also typically one would include resistors for the LEDs of the 7 Segment display (and technically also the placeholder LEDs) and a fitting one at the base of the transistor, so that no component gets destroyed due to too much current.

What exactly does "at times" mean? Randomly between individual simulation runs? And what do you mean by parallel and series in this case?

Well the ground cable was not supposed to go there. That was a mistake, But the two boards need to share a ground otherwise the Base of the transistor doesn't seem to take input.
Yes in-between simulations at times the power supply just doesn't work.

LEDs are not appropriate placeholders for fans. They behave completely differently. Your transistors need base resistors as to not overload your Arduino's GPIO pins and the fans (when implemented) should have flyback diodes because they are inductive loads.

At the moment I believe the transistors are in parallel since the voltage out the emitter is only around 4v. And for the fans to spin at a decent speed to move air I need the entire 12v output from the power supply.

Like this?
UpdatedTransistorBoard

Also, the loads (LEDs / fans) should be placed on the "high side". i.e. not between emitter and ground, but between P1+ (12V power rail) and emitter.

Per recommendation I changed out the LED's for DC motors I probably should've done that from the start but I just didn't think of the fact that the LED's weren't good stand ins thank you for that. The power supply not working between simulations might of just been a bug on tinkercad's since It seems to be fine now. However the motors are running in parallel still and only getting 3~4V which doesn't give them good rotation.

Tinkercad_Screenshot
Technical_Drawing_Motors

There is too much going on here. Remove everything that is not related to your current problem (LCD, 7-segment display, buttons) and keep just one motor. Once you have something that works reliably, you can add the missing stuff.

Here is how you drive an inductive load with an Arduino and an NPN
transistor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Please, note the common ground, the resistor on the base of the
transistor, the flyback diode, and the fact that the transistor is
mounted as a low-side switch.

Thank you for this diagram. I made a seperate circuit with just a singular motor following this and it worked flawlessly.

However when I add the other motors alongside the voltage drops to almost nothing meaning only one fan can run at a time.

Is the solution for this just a higher power supply and voltage regulators or can this be done with fancy wiring?

@Ironshi: Yous should be able to drive this way as many motors as you want. If the supply voltage drops, that's because you are exceeding the capacity of the power supply. Or maybe because it is a lab bench supply and you configured it to not deliver more than some specified maximum current.

I see it may be the limitations of the programs power supply then, Thank you for the help.
